# Execute a href after a jquery capture

Tags: jquery, function, href

I dont know if the title make sense but code worth a thousound word !

here is the  :

```
a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://campaignmonitor.com/blog&text=I love the Campaign Monitor blog!&via=campaignmonitor&related=yarrcat" id="tweeter">Tweet it</a>
```

and i have a jquery button  that capture the event click :

```
$('#tweeter').click(function(){
     do some var loading
    and do some validation... and then.. execute the href !
});
```

in fact i like the href to be done inside the jquery function... and then executed... the  could be a href="#"

Question, how do i said to the jquery function.... execute the href !

Comment: Code's actually worth about 1/78 of a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tweeter').click(function(e){
     do some var loading
    and do some validation... 
    if validation fails then e.preventDefault() 
    else don't do anything as the browser will continue and redirect to the link 
});
```